# How can I specify a smaller font than textAppearanceSmall?

Tags: android

In android, I can specify text appearance like this:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
```

Can you please tell me how can I specify a even smaller size than "textAppearaneSmall"?

Comment: Could you use android:textSize="5sp" for instance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also set the text size with the `dp` and `sp` units like this:

```
android:textSize="10sp"
```

Comment: It's recommended you use a minimum of 12sp.